# Running Mahout in Hadoop Cluster - java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, hadoop, mahout, mahout-recommender

I am trying to run the mahout code in the Hadoop cluster, it is throwing the below error.

> Error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
> org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.model.DataModel    at
> java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:387)    at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)     at
> sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)     at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)     at
> java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)   at
> java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)   at
> org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByNameOrNull(Configuration.java:2625)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:2590)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2686)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.JobContextImpl.getReducerClass(JobContextImpl.java:211)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runNewReducer(ReduceTask.java:614)
> at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:390)     at
> org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:178)  at
> java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
> javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)    at
> org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1878)
> at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:172)

Although it's working fine in local. Here's my pom.xml

```
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.24</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.mahout</groupId>
        <artifactId>mahout-core</artifactId>
        <version>0.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-math3</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.1</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Comment: It seems the mahout-core is not present in the classpath of the cluster, assuming the class in the error belongs to mentioned library. Is there a way you can check this?

Comment: You need to use hadoop-core 3.3.1 (or whatever version your cluster is ; all hadoop versions need to be the same)